# Creating javascript hooks possible?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a hook system in javascript as like as php ?

for an example ----

```
function myjsfunction(){

    call_my_function('handle_name');

}
```

now whatever function people add with 'handle' name it should get executed there.

like

```
add_to_function('handle_name', function(){alert('hi')});
add_to_function('handle_name', function(){alert('hello')});
```

both these functions should execute

Comment: So you are looking for js **and** php answer?

Comment: js anwer actually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var hooks = {};

function add_to_function(name, func) {
  if(!hooks[name]) hooks[name] = [];
  hooks[name].push(func);
}

function call_my_function(name, ...params){
  if(hooks[name]) 
     hooks[name].forEach(func => func(...params));
}
```

As functions are first class in js you can simply store them in an object.

Usecase:

```
add_to_function("log", console.log.bind(console, "this will log "));

call_my_function("log", "sth cool!");
```

Implementation with an IIFE:

http://jsbin.com/joxigabeyi/edit?console

Comment: WOW !!! going to try now, but is it possible avoiding that `var hooks` user defined variable ? means something global like dom or anything else... so that it will not be dependent of that user variable initialization

Comment: IIFE ? i am really not aware of this :(

Comment: @alice see updated snippet. BTW Immediatly Invoked Function Expression...